# Vb.net HMI like graphic

Tags: vb.net, draw, graphic

i would like to make a very simple HMI  where i use picturebox (no fancy ) as simple and link them together , the problem is that the pictures of symbols i use (although i use png with tranparent background ) when placed in a picturebox and needed to be on top of each others (in case for example a valve to be linked with a pipeline ) the picturebox on top will hide some of the other one's details and block it  so it doesn't look like one piece and something is missed .

i don't know what i really can do exactly to get rid of that

any sugestions are more than welcome
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: One possibility is to **draw** the symbols in the Paint() event of your PictureBox.  You'd need to store the location and symbol types in a List at class/form level.  Another option is to "clip" the individual PictureBox controls so they are no longer rectangular in nature.  This is done by creating a [GraphicsPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx) of the correct shape and setting the [Region()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the PictureBox to it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to place an control with layerd, but a best way is to create a new shape (with gdi+ drawing) on the canvas, with that, you can layer it as you want.

You can use Qt or exd++ or Visual Basic.net